# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-manifest

I have looked into the available questions on the stack overflow. But none fixes my issue.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(true) from [com.ecommpay:paymentpage-sdk-android:1.15.3] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-35
is also present at [com.jumio.android:iproov:4.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-36 value=(false).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:4-51:19 to override.
```

This is the top of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
android:allowBackup="true">
```

The available suggestions were to add `xmlns:tools` tag in the manifest, which doesn't fix my issue. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using tools:replace in wrong place it should be in your application tag not in manifest tag

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        ... >
        ...
    </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```